# Unity - SerilizeField and GetComponent not working when trying to use script components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a main script that takes in references to game objects that have a script called ButtonPress attached to them as components. To do this I have a SerializeField List in the main script so I can just drag and drop the buttons.
[image]

The problem is that when playing, I get a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error in the Start method of the main script when trying to do some setup for the buttons. However, this usually only happens for one or two buttons and if I delete the ButtonPress component on the buttons and add it back in the editor the error will go away until I open Unity again.

Start method of the main script:

```
[SerializeField] List<ButtonPress> buttons;
//more variables are removed here for simplicity

private void Start()
    {
        //pause the game and pull up pause menu when a settings button is pressed
        System.Action settingsAction = delegate () {
            pause();
            pauseMenuObject.GetComponent<IMenu>().pause();
        };

        //both the top and bottom pause buttons
        buttons[0].onPress(settingsAction);
        buttons[1].onPress(settingsAction); //<-------- in this case the error happened here
        //skip the intro transition when the game starts if the screen is pressed
        buttons[2].onPress(delegate () {
            mainCamera.GetComponent<camCtrl>().skipIntroTransition();
        });

        GameObject x = Instantiate(startingCandlePrefab);
        x.GetComponent<StartCandleFall>().setFields(startingCandleGravity, gameObject, mainCamera);
    }
```

I also tried another approach where I take references to the game objects of the buttons and then got the ButtonPress component:

```
[SerializeField] List<GameObject> buttonObjects;
List<ButtonPress> buttons;
//more variables are removed here for simplicity

private void Start()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < buttonObjects.Count; i++) {
            Debug.Log(buttonObjects[i].name);
            buttons.Add(buttonObjects[i].GetComponent<ButtonPress>()); <---- error happens here
        }

        //pause the game and pull up pause menu when a settings button is pressed
        System.Action settingsAction = delegate () {
            pause();
            pauseMenuObject.GetComponent<IMenu>().pause();
        };

        //both the top and bottom pause buttons
        buttons[0].onPress(settingsAction);
        buttons[1].onPress(settingsAction);
        //skip the intro transition when the game starts if the screen is pressed
        buttons[2].onPress(delegate () {
            mainCamera.GetComponent<camCtrl>().skipIntroTransition();
        });

        GameObject x = Instantiate(startingCandlePrefab);
        x.GetComponent<StartCandleFall>().setFields(startingCandleGravity, gameObject, mainCamera);

    }
```

In this case the error is the same but always happens when trying to use GetComponent on the first button despite the debug.log successfully showing the name of the first button.

I have double checked that each object has a ButtonPress script on it and I didn't misspell it. I'm not sure why the GetComponent would return null here unless the game objects haven't fully loaded yet, but I also thought that they would be fully loaded by the time the Start method runs.

Comment: Instead of the log please use a breakpoint and [debug the code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) .. for instance just because the name appears in the console doesn't mean it is necessarily the correct instance of your component you are looking at ... do you maybe have an unintended instance of your component that was accidentally dropped onto the wrong object and then forgotten (happens more often than you think ;) )

Comment: in your second code for instance the error happens because `List<ButtonPress> buttons` is not initialized and `null` ... you would need to either do it on field initialization `List<ButtonPress> buttons = new ();` or latest before your loop in `Start` do `buttons = new (buttonObjects.Count);`

Comment: in the first picture all 3 for sure have button press scripts, so the error on that makes no sense, except if perhaps that button has been destroyed.  In the second script there is a chance that said gameobject has no button press so that would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and sorry for the super late reply!! I was able to narrow down the issue to it only being caused by buttons that were copied from another button or buttons that were prefabs. Recreating the button from scratch but otherwise making it identical will not cause the issue to happen. This isn't a huge problem since there are only 3 buttons that are identical but its something that I would like to figure out to avoid future problems.